# Negating number_format() result changes number of significant digits?

Tags: php, math, floating-point

I have a website that allows users to purchase products through PayPal and I allow discount codes. I was adding the discount like this:

```
'cost'   => -number_format($discount, 2)
```

However, sometimes PayPal would throw an error when I tried checking out.

Debugging, I found that sometimes the value of `cost` would be something like `-8.066666666667`. I was initially perplexed, but found moving the negation operator inside the parameter list (before the first parameter) fixed the issue.

I want to make sure I understand what happened so I don't make the same mistake again. I'm thinking it went down like this:

- `number_format($discount, 2)` apparently returns a string (I thought it returned float)
- putting negation operator in front of number_format()` will cause the returned string result to be converted automatically to floating point, which will have rounding errors
- after the conversion from string to floating point, the opposite (negated) result is returned
- the returned result is not rounded to two decimal places

Is my understanding of what happened correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're getting the number_format function wrong.
This function transforms a `float` into a `string` by making it pleasant to read. According to the manual, this function also adds commas in between any group of three digits to make the resulting number easier to read and a trailing dot followed by the decimal digits if required.

This messes up with your code, that is in fact negating a string. Negating a string makes no sense in general :)

What you would like to have instead is a function that rounds a float to a given number of decimal digits. This is achieved by means of the `round` function:

```
round(19.0398, 2); // returns 19.04
```

With respect to your understanding, it is mostly correct but you are missing an important subtle case.

As I said, number_format returns a string, now if you negate a string that string is automatically transformed into a number. How does the translation of a string into a number works? The initial part of the string (that is composed by numbers) will be transformed into a number, but all characters starting from the first that is not a digit will be ignored.

So, turning the string "12a33" into a number will result in the number 12, while the string "17,500" will be transformed in the number 17.

Can you see the problem now? If your discount variable contains a large number, let say `10000`, `number_format(10000, 2)` will result in the string `"10,000"` and negating such string will result in the number `-10`.

I don't know if `$discount` will ever be that large but you should consider using `round` instead of `number_format` for your purpose.

Comment: Whoa! That is an excellent point! I made an IDE One to test: https://ideone.com/ZFaMUI

Answer (score 2):

It should be...

```
'cost'   => '-' . number_format($discount, 2)
```

... or just ...

```
'cost'   => number_format(-$discount, 2)
```

... if you want to get a *string* as the corresponding value (and you probably do).

With the code as it stands, you first get the string (result of `number_format` call) only to cast back to number with unary minus operator. And that number hits the same [wall of floating point inaccuracies](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) as before.

Comment: That's a really good point, I didn't think of that! Working with money in PHP and MySQL so confusing..

Answer (score 0):

This will make it work,

```
'cost' => number_format(-1*$discount, 2)
```

Comment: How exactly `-1*$discount` is better than just `-$discount`? )